# Got to think we're due. - meaning?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I know "due" can mean expected, owed, deserved..but I do not get it in this context (subtitles for the Walking Dead):

```
<i>We've made it 500 miles.</i>

<i>Maybe this can be the easy part.</i>

**Got to think we're due.**

Give us 20 minutes to check in.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context, if this could be the "easy part" they are due (owed) something easy.  I'm assuming that things up to this point were difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It means *anticipated*, referring to a possibly upcoming event.  A shortened form of "overdue".  Contrary to [Melissa's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/226587/106801), the group may have experienced an *easy* period and should expect things to turn south at any minute.

> I think we're due [for an attack].

Answer (score 1):

It means

> I have no choice but to think something's going to happen.

Or

> (Something leads me to believe) something's going to happen.

It could be a positive expectation or a negative expectation in this context. We cannot tell from this excerpt alone what "this" refers to in "this can be the easy part."

The speaker's use of "got" suggests that he or she may be reluctant to think it, and therefore it is a prediction that something bad will happen.

However, it could also mean something like a concept of balance or fairness forces him or her to conclude that they were owed this recent peace after previous trials.